# Reducing equations using R

Tags: r, math

I've got this small snippet for reducing a large system:

```
# set up the multipliers
g1 = (s+9)/((s)*(s+6)*(s+12)*(s+14))
g2 = ((6)*(s+9)*(s+17))/((s+12)*(s+32)*(s+68))
h1 = 13
h2 = 1/(s+7)

# reduce the system in parts
s1 = (g2)/(1 + (g2)*(h1))
s2 = (s1)*(g1)
s3 = (s2)/(1 + (s2)*(h2))

# now we have a unity feedback
g = s3
show(g)
```

`g` *should* be the reduced equation from doing the operations above. However, I get a bunch of errors when I run the code:

```
Error : object 's' not found
Error : object 's' not found
Error : object 's' not found
Error : object 'g2' not found
Error : object 's1' not found
Error : object 's2' not found
Error : object 's3' not found
Error : error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'show': Error: object 'g' not found
```

Am I not using equations correctly?

edit: my intentions are to have `s` as a free variable

Comment: See @Joran's comment to DMCs answer.

Comment: It looks like you want a computer algebra system. There are some free systems that could be useful to you, e.g., [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net), [Sympy](http://sympy.org), [Sage](http://sagemath.org). What you have there looks like the result of a Laplace transform. There is a package named "coma" in Maxima which could be useful in this context. Probably Sympy and Sage have similar packages, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to evaluate your first line of code, there must be an object `s` that is already defined.

It sounds like your goal is to create a function that outputs `g` from a single input `s`. The below code wraps your calculations in a function called `make_g`:

```
make_g <- function(s){

  # set up the multipliers
  g1 = (s+9)/((s)*(s+6)*(s+12)*(s+14))
  g2 = ((6)*(s+9)*(s+17))/((s+12)*(s+32)*(s+68))
  h1 = 13
  h2 = 1/(s+7)

  # reduce the system in parts
  s1 = (g2)/(1 + (g2)*(h1))
  s2 = (s1)*(g1)
  s3 = (s2)/(1 + (s2)*(h2))

  # now we have a unity feedback
  g = s3

  g

}
```

Now, you can call the functions using whatever value for `s` you like:

```
make_g(s = 1)
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction! However, how can I see the actual equation of `g`. I would like to *see* `g(s)`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *see*. You can visualize the relationship with a plot: `s <- seq(0, 1, by = .01); plot(s, make_g(s))`

Comment: The OP may be under the impression that R is like a computer algebra system, like Maple or Mathematica, but it is not. There are some packages that provide some functionality along those lines, though.

Comment: @joran, you're right - that's definitely what I had assumed. I'm going accept this answer because it does give me what I want. I'll probably explore Mathematica.